# Where to find dumped data (using dump command in Neo4j Shell) in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, export, dump

Wondering where to find the dumped file of neo4j dump command. I was running Neo4j v2.1.3 in windows operating system. Please help thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the dump command just outputs to the console, so you need to redirect the output.  Something like:

```
Neo4jShell.bat -c "dump match (n:People)-[:Shared]-(m) return n,m;" > social.connection.db\test2.cql
```

**Edited with the Windows version of the command**

For UNIX systems a similar command works:

```
neo4j-shell -c "dump match (n:People)-[:Shared]-(m) return n,m;" > social.connection.db/test2.cql
```

Comment: I tried to execute this statement 

Neo4jShell.bat -c dump "match (n:People)-[:Shared]-(m) return n,m;" > social.connection.db\test2.cql

but it dumps the whole database.

Comment: Maybe try shifting your quote because `dump` is part of the cypher command you're sending to the shell.  Like this: `Neo4jShell.bat -c "dump match (n:People)-[:Shared]-(m) return n,m;" > social.connection.db\test2.cql`

Comment: I tried this but got an exception when I open the file:
missing brackets